# iOS beacon region monitoring require to enable bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-location, ibeacon

I am developing an app which has beacon region monitoring.Below is the code for monitoring beacon region.

```
-(void)setBeaconMonitoringForUUID:(NSString *)strID withMajor:(NSString *)strMajor withMinor:(NSString *)strMinor withIdentifier:(NSString *)strIdentifier {
    NSUUID *strUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:strID];
    CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:strUUID major:[strMajor intValue] minor:[strMinor intValue] identifier:strIdentifier];
    [beaconRegion setNotifyEntryStateOnDisplay:YES];
    [beaconRegion setNotifyOnEntry:YES];
    [beaconRegion setNotifyOnExit:YES];
    [self.objLocationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];    
    [self.objLocationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];}
```

and the locationManager initialization is as below

```
- (id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self != nil)
   {
      self.objLocationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
      self.objLocationManager.delegate = self;
      self.objLocationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0;
      self.objLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
      self.objLocationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;

      if ([self.objLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.objLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
      }    
      [self.objLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

  }
  return self;
}
```

Now the question is for monitoring beacon region the iOS device must have to enable bluetooth or its working without turn on bluetooth?.I have also refer the below link but there is no explanation about to enable bluetooth for region monitoring
[Determining the Availability of Region Monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html)

I have test with kontakt.io beacon and its not working without turning on bluetooth on device but as i read the region monitoring is working on Location service then why we need to enable bluetooth.so every beacon   require to turn on bluetooth or it is specific to kontakt.io beacon?

Comment: Yes, Definitely. Beacons works on Bluetooth only. Because Bluetooth uses very less batteries compare to other wireless networks. When your phone comes to it's range, it'll perform it's operations to your phone.

Comment: @DipakKacha if beacon work on bluetooth only they why we need request location "always" or “when in use” and the didEnterRegion and didExitRegion methods are from CLLocationManager.

Answer (score 5):

**Apple made a change in iOS 11 so that even if the user disables bluetooth in Control Center, scans for and detections of iBeacon devices are still performed** by the operating system. (Control Center is the quick access pane you get by swiping up from the bottom of the screen on iOS.) See here for more details:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208086

The above statement is not true for iOS 10.x and earlier, where turning off bluetooth in Control Center will disable beacon detection.  And as @Paulw11 states in his answer, you must also have location enabled on the phone, and the app must obtain a dynamic location permission from the app before it can detect beacons.

Also on all versions of iOS, if you go to Settings -> Bluetooth and disable bluetooth it will disable beacon detection.

Comment: so for all version of iOS i need to check both permission Location and Bluetooth for detecting beacon?

Comment: Yes, but to be precise, Bluetooth is not a permission on iOS, it is a setting.  It must be on.  Location is both a setting and a permission.  Location must be on, and location permission must be granted to your app.

Comment: @davidgyoung First you're saying that on iOS 11 even if the user disables Bluetooth in Control Center the scan for beacon devices will still be performed and then you say the opposite, that if the Bluetooth is disabled in settings it will not perform the scans. I'm pretty sure the toggling in Control Center and in Settings is not handled differently by the system. If it is, do you have any prove for this strange behavior?

Comment: The link in my answer shows Apple's documentation for the new iOS 11 behavior on Control Center.

Answer (score 1):

iBeacons use Bluetooth Low Energy to advertise themselves, so the Bluetooth setting on the iOS device must be on in order to receive the signal.

Since detection of a beacon can be used to determine a user's location by correlating the detection of a beacon with the known location of the beacon you must obtain the user's permission to use their location.

Comment: Thanks for answer i have check with estimote beacon and  it will trigger enter/exit  region event even if bluetooth is turn off on device.so the confusion is it  different characteristics by beacon to beacon?

Comment: No, no beacon can work without bluetooth.  Some frameworks may use `CLCircularRegion`s, which use GPS and Cell/WiFi location as well as `CLBeaconRegion`s, but if it is pure `CLBeaconRegion` then Bluetooth is required.

Comment: To clarify, since iOS11 there are two stages of "bluetooth enabled". It can be enabled in settings but "disabled" in control panel, which basically means new connections are not allowed but beacons, Apple watch and other things still work.